# Where do the celery default logs get stored?

Tags: django, logging, celery

Where do celery default logs get stored? I am starting **celery worker** with `screen` with no `-f` arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account celery is a messaging library over its message broker, you should probably look for where the broker keeps its logs. For instance, if you use RabbitMQ they are going to be in `/var/log/rabbitmq` and they will have the name of the node (rabbit by defaut) and machine, so you'll have a bunch of rabbit@yourlocalhostname.log, and also the result of the rotating logs which will be compressed with .gz